# How can I see if a value is contained in an Array or Class?

Tags: c#, data-structures, storage

I am making a BlackJack game.  I need to determine if my deck contains a particular value.

What would be the easiest way to check my deck.  Easiest meaning less lines of code and less confusing.  Note I will be giving these values relevant strings. (King, Jack, Queen and Ten would equal 10.)

This does not involve anything about suits or colour.  I will be showing just the card symbol (K, Q).

```
            enum deck {Ace=1|11, Two=2, Three=3, Four=4, Five=5, Six=6, Seven=7, Eight=8, Nine=9, Ten=10, Jack=10, Queen=10, King=10};

        int a = (int)deck.Ace;
        int b = (int)deck.Two;
        int c = (int)deck.Three;
        int d = (int)deck.Four;
        int e = (int)deck.Five;
        int f = (int)deck.Six;
        int g = (int)deck.Seven;
        int h = (int)deck.Eight;
        int i = (int)deck.Nine;
        int j = (int)deck.Ten;
        int k = (int)deck.Jack;
        int l = (int)deck.Queen;
        int m = (int)deck.King;
```

Comment: Consider using two Enumerable types, one for the suit and one for the number.

Comment: @Doc: You mean `Enum`s, which are completely unrelated to the `Enumerable` static class or the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, years of c# and never knew that.  Glad you pointed that out, I need to rethink my life.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How are you currently storing your cards?  What does your `Card` class look like?  There is a *lot* of relevant information out there on this subject.  There are a lot of different data structures out there, most all of which are capable of being searched.  Since you're unlikely to have a very large data set, you shouldn't need to worry about efficiency.  Just try one; see what happens.  Experiment a bit and look up other people's solutions if you have trouble.  If you still can't get it working, post your code here.

Comment: Forget about suit and colour, and enums you need flags or something too confusing for me, I do not know how to use these enums for selecting them randomly as a card - if that makes sense?

Comment: I've tried doing a card class got quite far with it, then users started posting about these enums which looked straight forward enough but figured out a lot of my code was missing.

Comment: @Mr.Bottel, take it from someone who was once new to C#, it's much better to learn about something new, like enums, if they were designed to make your job easier.  And oh, how they do.

Comment: @Servy this is why you don't edit peoples questions, "C# Newbie" people are posting loads of code for me which I can't hardly understand :S

Comment: @Mr.Bottell Enums are very basic indeed, and something that even "newbies" should understand!

Comment: @Mr.Bottell Then spend some time learning about what their answers contain.  Most all of the answer here are quite basic; if you don't understand them then I can't think of *any* solution worth using that you would.  You need to be prepared to spend some time learning new concepts, looking up further information about the material included, experimenting with them on your own, etc. for you to solve your problem.  I don't see any possible way around that here.

Comment: Not with my teacher it isn't

Comment: @Mr.Bottell I'm not sure what you're responding to.  Are you saying your teacher has forbidden you from learning more about programming?  If so, ditch him and get a better teacher who understands that learning new programming concepts on your own is a *vital* skill that all developers *need* to start developing from the very start.  If that's not what you're saying, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Servy right I have read up on enums and I think I have managed to create my deck and made variables, could you look over the code to see if it is ok, if so, how would I go about selecting one of these variables at random to be one of the cards? (I shall edit my question)

Comment: Using `1 | 11` won't really do what you think it does for your `Ace`.  It's doing a bitwise OR, so the result is just `11`.  Also you don't want to have several enum values all backed by the same number; it won't really work properly if you do that.  To generate a random number use the `Random` class.  To select an item at random from a a group of items, generate a random index into the collection of items.

Comment: Won? What do you mean

Comment: I hit enter too soon, see edit.

Comment: So what would you recommend I do for the ace, and how would it not work properly with having the same values with 10, J...?

Comment: The Ace can have two values, 1 or 11. It is difficult to tell a value because it depends on the situation and is at best chosen by a player.

Answer (score 2):

I would use one enum to represent the rank and another to represent the suit.

Then encapsulate those in a `Card` class like so:

```
public enum Suit
{
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts,
    Spades
}

public enum Rank
{
    Ace = 1,
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King
}

public class Card: IEquatable<Card>
{
    public Rank Rank
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public Suit Suit
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Rank)
            {
                case Rank.Ten:
                case Rank.Jack:
                case Rank.Queen:
                case Rank.King:

                    return 10;

                default:

                    return (int) Rank;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to note here is the `Equals()` method which is part of the `IEquatable` interface. Implementing this allows us to leverage search methods such as `List.Contains()`.

With the above code, you can write stuff like this:

```
List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();

deck.Add(new Card {Rank = Rank.Seven, Suit = Suit.Clubs} ); 
deck.Add(new Card {Rank = Rank.Five,  Suit = Suit.Diamonds} );

Card target1 = new Card {Rank = Rank.Five,  Suit = Suit.Diamonds };
Card target2 = new Card {Rank = Rank.Eight, Suit = Suit.Hearts };

Console.WriteLine(deck.Contains(target1)); // Prints true
Console.WriteLine(deck.Contains(target2)); // Prints false

Console.WriteLine(deck.IndexOf(target1)); // Prints 1
```

Note how we can use `deck.Contains(target)` to see if the deck contains a particular card.

We can also use `IndexOf(target)` to find exactly where in the deck the card is.

Also note how we implemented the Card's `Value` property.

We don't need to store this value explicitly because you can derive it from the card's rank.

See how we return explicit values for Ten, jack, Queen and King. For the other values, we take advantage of the fact that the enum values for the ranks start with 1 for Ace, 2 for Two and so on. This means we can simply cast the enum into an int to get the correct value.

With this foundation, it will be easier to create a `Deck` and a `Hand` class to simulate a deck of cards and a hand of cards, and also to do things like shuffle the deck. (How to do that is beyond the scope of this particular question and answer.)

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't edit my question, the 2nd box of code here is too confusing, contains suits which is irrelevant. But thanks for trying

Comment: @Mr.Bottell What do you mean "shouldn't edit my question"? I didn't edit your question! Anyway, if you find this too confusing and aren't prepared to learn basic stuff, you won't have a hope of writing a Blackjack game; I suggest you go and do something less taxing instead.

Comment: sorry not you, that was meant for servy

Comment: `Value` could just be implemented as `Math.Min(10, Rank)` rather than a switch.

Comment: @Mr.Bottell I'm rather confident that even if I hadn't edited your "I'm a newbie" comment out of your question it wouldn't have changed Matt's answer here.  It doesn't really get more basic than this while still being an appropriate solution to your problem.

Comment: @Servy true, but I wanted to demonstrate using a switch (maybe he wants an ace to be 13, it sometimes is)

Comment: @MatthewWatson You mean 11 ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am writing the blackjack game in a windows form application, not console application, is all your code still valid for a form?

Comment: @Mr.Bottell Yes, it doesn't use any user interface at all, so it will work with either a console or a windows forms app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enums`:

```
public enum Value
{
    V2,
    V3,
    //...
    V10,
    J,
    Q,
    K,
    A
}
public enum Suit
{
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Clubs
}

public static bool ContainsCard(IEnumerable<Tuple<Suit,Value>> deck, Suit suit, Value value)
{
    return deck.Any(c => c.Item1 == suit && c.Item2 == value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of acceptable ways to go about this problem.  One way I would try is making two types of **enum** and assigning them for each card.  For example,

```
public enum CardNumber { Ace, Two, Three, ... Ten, Jack, Queen, King };
public enum CardSuit { Diamond, Heart, Club, Spade};
```

Once these two types have been created, you can declare one of each of the above for every card you make.  The cards, at this point, could be easily stored in your preferred system - such as an Array or List.

Comment: This isn't showing how to search a data structure, it's showing how to represent a `Card`.  That's a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052091/array-for-blackjack-cards-strings-or-integers).

Comment: numeric literals are not allowed as enum member identifiers.